# Sharded counters within transaction

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, sharding

Taken from [this artice](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters#implv2_python) on Sharding Counters, the following function demonstrates how a random shard is selected before it is incremented. This happens within a transaction.

```
def increment():
    """Increment the value for a given sharded counter."""
    def txn():
        index = random.randint(0, NUM_SHARDS - 1)
        shard_name = "shard" + str(index)
        counter = SimpleCounterShard.get_by_key_name(shard_name)
        if counter is None:
            counter = SimpleCounterShard(key_name=shard_name)
        counter.count += 1
        counter.put()
    db.run_in_transaction(txn)
```

Can only one transaction take place at a time and would that not prevent the different(random) sharded counters to be updated simultaneously? 
If so, what is the purpose of the sharding counters if only one sharded counter can be updated at a time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transactions lock all the entities involved with the transaction.  You can have multiple transactions going on as long as they're not touching the same entities.

Each shard is a separate entity.  This allows you to update the various shards at the same time.

If the transaction happens to attempt to hit a shard (due to the random number generator) that is already in a transaction, then the transaction would fail.

Comment: When a transaction fails, it attempts a retry a few times (I think 5) before failing for good, which in this case should succeed in picking a non-locked shard eventually.

Comment: Wrong: transactions on GAE do not do locking: they use optimistic concurrency control, meaning that when transaction is committed it checks internal versioning field and if changed (= someone else changed values at the same time) it throws an exception: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#What_Can_Be_Done_In_a_Transaction

Comment: The python api, via db.run_in_transaction, will try 3 times.

Answer (score 3):

No, this are separate transactions which do not block each other and also write limitation only applies to each entity separately.

Rationale: in your case `SimpleCounterShard` entities do not have a parent, meaning each entity is the root of it's own entity group. The transactions' scope is entity group and also concurrent write limit applies to entity group.

Comment: Question: Is it viable to use a sharded count (hash it) and use it as unique String key for a GAE Entity, would it (the generated count for a given type) not collide at some point?\

Comment: @xybrek Not sure I understand this, but: of course it would collide - same count value would create the same hash value and thus the same key. So different counters with the same count value would create the same key and overwrite each other. Also, even without collision, how is this supposed to work? Every time a counter value changes you would create a new Entity?

Comment: not create new Entity for each counter change, but use counter value as ID for the Entity, as  I need that the entities ID's would start with 1 (or at least a very small long value), and so forth. GAE generates quite long Long values which would defeat the purpose of my app

Comment: Yes, like a method incrementCounterGetValue() to get a long value to assign as long id.